# Are there any ways to use Apple Pay in the Expo app to generate a payment token?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, applepay

Are there any ways to use Apple Pay in the Expo app to generate a payment token? without ejecting from expo app to react native

was expecting payment token to be generated through react native payment package but expo go wont support it

Answer (score 0):

If you use stripe then you should be able to enable apple pay with stripe and users will be able to use it.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/stripe/